# function _inherits babel after transpiling

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm not good at English. But I can not get an answer to the question...
I have some code ES2015:

```
class Animal{}
class Rabbit extends Animal{}
```

After transpiling this code I get function _inherits.
I just can not understand what the last expression does:

```
if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
```

In my opinion, the last but one does the same. Together:

```
function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code basically calls `Object.setPrototypeOf` (ES6) and falls back to `__proto__` for preES6 browsers. That fall back is not the default as `__proto__` is a property that shouldn't actually exist. It was added to the spec to create consistency between browsers, Chrome added it as an "experimental, don't do this", then it was added to the spec as it was commonly used. With `__proto__` however you can break a lot of things, not to mention every optimization the browser could make:

```
 Function.prototype.__proto__ = new Proxy({}, { get(k){ return "test" } });

 console.log((function() { }).t);
```

therefore using `__proto__` causes some trouble for the browser as it has to rollback nearly all optimizations. `Object.setPrototypeOf` however was added purposely to the language and has a more strict, and therefore non-risky usage, using it will break *some* optimizations but not all, therefore it is much better to use this if possible.

Comment: thanks! But I don’t understand why the `SubClass .__ proto __` gets the value `SuperClass` in this example?

Comment: @Андрей so that SubClass inherits all static properties / methods from SuperClass

Comment: That is, the first instruction copies the prototype, and the second one has its own superclass properties?

Comment: @Андрей yes exactly, so if you got `SuperClass.constant = 1;` then that will be inherited to `SubClass.constant`

Comment: Thank you so much, Jonas Wilms!